# Do you know any calculatoer where can I calculate dividing of some IP address to several others?

Tags: subnet, broadcast, prefix, ip-range

I would like to divide this ip address into
1)First LAN for 10 computer
2)Reserve for 3 computers
3)Reserve for 2 computers

I need to know First ip, last ip, brodcast and prefix.
Do you know any online calculator tool for this?

Comment: Sorry, resource or product recommendations are explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. The linked question has all your answers though.